# (Dafny) Sorting an array - loop invariant

Tags: sorting, verification, loop-invariant, dafny

Here is a simple **sort algorithm** written in **Dafny** :

```
predicate perm(a:array<int>, b:array<int>)
    requires a != null && b != null
    reads a,b
{
    multiset(a[..]) == multiset(b[..])
}

predicate sorted(a:array<int>, min:int, max:int)
    requires a != null
    requires 0 <= min <= max <= a.Length 
    reads a
{
    forall i,j | min <= i < j < max :: a[i] <= a[j] 
}
method sort(a:array<int>)
    requires a != null
    requires a.Length >= 1
    modifies a
    ensures perm(a,old(a))
    ensures sorted(a, 0, a.Length)
    
{
    var i := 1;
    while i < a.Length 
        invariant perm(a,old(a))
        invariant 1 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant sorted(a, 0, i)       
        decreases a.Length-i
    {
        var j := i;
    
        while j > 0 && a[j-1] > a[j] 
            invariant perm(a,old(a))
            invariant 1 <= i <= a.Length-1
            invariant 0 <= j <= i
            invariant sorted(a,0,j)
            invariant sorted(a,j,i+1) //MIGHT NOT BE MAINTAINED IF I REMOVE THE NEXT INVARIANT
            invariant forall m,n | 0 <= m < j < n <= i :: a[m] <= a[n]
            decreases j
        {
            a[j], a[j-1] := a[j-1], a[j];
            j := j-1;
        }
        i := i+1;
    }
}
```

The code has **no error**. However, if I remove the invariant `forall m,n | 0 <= m < j < n <= i :: a[m] <= a[n]` out of the inner loop, **Dafny** tells me that the invariant `sorted(a,j,i+1)`might not be maintained by the loop.

1. **Why is that?**
2. **How can one guess that the invariant** `forall m,n | 0 <= m < j < n <= i :: a[m] <= a[n]` **is needed in the first place?**

   I have tried to prove this program on paper but I did not need this invariant when constructing the inner loop's invariants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is `sorted(a,j,i+1)` not maintained without the extra invariant?

Remember what verifying a loop invariant requires. It requires starting in an *arbitrary* state satisfying the loop invariant, executing the loop body, and then proving you end in a state satisfying the loop invariant. In other words, nothing beyond the loop invariants can be assumed.

Without the extra loop invariant, nothing stops the region `a[0..j]` from containing elements larger than `a[j..i+1]`. In particular, while the loop is executing, we know that `a[j-1] > a[j]`, so what's to say that `a[j-1]` isn't also larger than every `a[k]` with `k >= j`?

### How can we guess the extra invariant?

One way to think about the inner loop of insertion sort is that it maintains an invariant kind of like "`a` is sorted except at `a[j]`". In fact, it maintains something slightly stronger, which is that "`a` is sorted, except that `a[j]` might be out of order (ie, smaller) than any `a[k]` with `k < j`.

We can express this as a modified version of your `sorted` predicate:

```
invariant forall m,n | 0 <= m < n < i+1 && n != j :: a[m] <= a[n]
```

which says that `a` is sorted at all pairs of indices *except* for those where the second index is `j`.

In fact, the inner loop verifies with just this invariant (ie, without either of the `sorted` invariants or the "extra" invariant).

We can look at your "extra" invariant as another way of expressing this more concise invariant when conjoined with `sorted(a,0,j)` and `sorted(a,j,i+1)`. For any pair of indices, if they both fall below `j`, then `sorted(a,0,j)` applies. If they both fall above or at `j`, then `sorted(a,j,i+1)` applies. If one falls below `j` and one strictly above `j`, then the extra invariant applies. The only remaining case is when the larger index is exactly `j`, but this is the case ruled out by the concise statement.